# Why did Fernando Torres win the Golden Boot at Euro 2012?

Tags: rules, football, euro, awards, uefa

Euro 2012 has now ended.

Why has Fernando Torres won the golden boot when the following players also had 3 goals?

1. Mario Gomez (Germany)
2. Alan Dzagoyev (Russia)
3. Mario Mandzukic (Croatia)
4. Mario Balotelli (Italy)
5. Cristiano Ronaldo (Portugal)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Torres won the Golden Boot because he was the most effective..

In the event of a tie, the Golden Boot will be awarded to the player with the most assists.
In a further tie, the winner will be the player spending the least time playing in the tournament(i.e On the pitch).
Fernando Torres secured one assist, the same as Mario Gomez, but spent a total of 189 minutes on the pitch compared to 281 minutes by Mario Gomez of Germany.

Over-all topscorer for Euro 2012 including qualification is Klaas-Jan Huntelaar (Netherlands) who scored 12 goals.

[image]